# Web Form Response Status Code Always 200 in ajax with Controller

Tags: asp.net, ajax, webforms, controller, http-status-codes

i have an Ajax in my web form that calls a ActionResault in a Controller .the problem is that even though i set the Response Statuse Code To anything But 200 (404 ,401,...) The Ajax Will Get a 200 Response So there wont be Any Error In Ajax Here is My Ajax And Controller :

```
$.ajax({

            beforeSend: function (jqXHR, settings) {
                xhr = jqXHR;  // To get the ajax XmlHttpRequest 
            },
            url: url + "Accounts/Login",
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            data: JSON.stringify(loginDataModel),

            success: function (result) {
                alert(result);
                if (result==0) {
                    document.location.href = '/Controlpanel/DashBoard.aspx';
                }

            }, error: function (jqXHR, exception) {

                var msg = '';

                if (jqXHR.status === 0) {
                    msg = 'عدم اتصال به اینترنت';
                } else if (jqXHR.status == 401) {
                    msg = 'اطلاعات وارد شده صحیح نمی باشد';
                } else if (jqXHR.status == 500) {
                    msg = 'خطایی در هنگام پردازش درخواست شما رخ داد.';
                } else if (exception === 'parsererror') {
                    msg = 'Requested JSON parse failed.';
                } else if (exception === 'timeout') {
                    msg = 'درخواست شما در بازه زمانی مورد نظر پردازش نشد';
                } else if (exception === 'abort') {
                    msg = 'Ajax request aborted.';
                } else {
                    msg = $.parseJSON(jqXHR.responseText).ErrorMessage;
                }
                $(".message").text(msg);

            },

        })
```

And This is my ActionResault

```
 public  HttpStatusCodeResult Login(LoginBindingProcessModel loginDataModel)
    {
        if (userRole != null)
        {
            HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication.SignIn(new Microsoft.Owin.Security.AuthenticationProperties { IsPersistent = loginDataModel.isPersistent }, userRole);
        }
        if (objUserVerification == UserVerificationResult.SuccessfullyVerified)
        {
            Response.StatusCode = (int)System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK;
            return Json(objUserVerification);
        }
        else
        {
            Response.StatusCode = (int)System.Net.HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized;
            return Json(objUserVerification);
        }
    }
```

any help would be appreciated

Comment: That action result code should not compile as `HttpStatusCodeResult` and `JsonResult` are not assignable and cannot implicitly convert one to the other.

Comment: @Nkosi Thanks For Your Help .so You Suggest that i change the return Type of ActionResault ?

Comment: I didn't suggest anything. I was stating that what you currently have should not even compile for you to be getting the behavior you described. You could change the return type of the action to the lowest common type which would be `ActionResult` as a start, then look into why you are getting the described behavior.

Comment: @Nkosi Thanks For your Help :)

Answer (score 0):

it turned out the problem was on 401 . because owin Redirects the page to Default Address on Unauthorized Status Code .